# Integrating 0 over a simple complex area containing 0

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

This should, I think, by rights, be easier for me to do. That said, I can't.

$$\iint_D0 dA$$
$D$ is a simple area over a complex plane, with simple closed, positively
oriented boundary, $D'$, where the boundary is a curve.
Can someone help me with this integral? Is it anything?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses almost no theoretical results at all, and certainly nothing very abstract. We know that $0 = 0+0$, and we also know that $\iint_D(f+g)dA = \iint_D f\,dA + \iint_Dg\,dA$. This gives
$$
\iint_D 0\,dA = \iint_D0\,dA + \iint_D0\,dA
$$
and the only number that satisfies $x = x+x$ is $0$, so that must be the answer.

Comment: Thought so. This is part of a another question, so clearly I am VERY VERY wrong. Which saddens me.

Comment: You can use linearity of the integral in a different way to show this, too: $\iint_D0\,dA=0\iint_DdA=0$.

Comment: Actually, $x+x=x$ is also solved by $x=\infty$ hence one would first need to show the result is a finite number for the argument to be convincing.